# How to quickly check if a date (or time) exists in a large XTS object?

Tags: r, rcpp, xts, zoo

I have a very large xts object in R called `Data` with 10s or 100s of rows and millions of rows per day.

Here is my current code:

```
Data #my xts data set.

myDate <- "2018-02-15"
if(nrow(Data[as.character(myDate)]) > 0)
   #Run code.
```

The problem is that the subset of the 1 day has millions of lines and takes a significant amount of time, especially if I am checking many dates.

Is there a way I can check for the existence of a date or only get the first occurrence of a date such that such that I don't waste time extracting large amounts of data?

I would like to do this in native R, but a Rcpp solution is most welcome.

Thank you.

EDIT:
From ngm's answer I was able to complete an Rcpp solution.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool doesDateExist(const Rcpp::NumericMatrix& Data, double startDate, double maxDiff = 86400)
{
  double endDate = startDate + maxDiff;
  NumericVector time = Data.attr("index");
  for(int ii = 0; ii < Data.nrow();ii++)
  {
     if(time(ii) >= startDate)
     {
       if(time(ii) < endDate)
          return true;
       else
         return false;
     }
  }
  return false;
}
```

And to use it I have:

```
myDate <-as.POSIXct("2018-02-15", tz = indexTZ(Data))
if(doesDateExist(Data, myDate, 86400))
   #Run code.
```

The as.POSIXct being my missing piece that I always forget about.

Edit: Added ptional field to rcpp code for max time difference. 86400 seconds for day, 3600 for hour 60 for minute and so on.

Comment: `sum(Data %in% myDate)`

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. It takes longer than extracting data and still does not give me the correct result. I don't know how it works but entered exactly as listed gives a result of 0 when data exists.

Comment: I used to use `xts` pretty exclusively, but more recently also used `data.table` for this which has its advantage.  You can split into days and times easily and group and filter by those.   Lastly, the comparison operations are already vectorized so your Rcpp solution, nice as it is, is not really needed.  (And you could use `DatetimeVector` for the datetime attribute, and `Datetime` for the object you compare to.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be faster to access the index of your `xts` object directly.

It looks like you are trying to see if a particular date is contained in the date part of the index of your `xts` object. This works for me:

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix, descr='my new xts object')

myDate <- as.POSIXct("2007-01-04")

myDate %in% as.POSIXct(index(sample.xts), format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: It is very fast, but it does not work for me and I think that my xts object contains time as well. It might have "2007-01-04 T00:01" which is in the day but comes up as false. I think all that is missing is to compare against only the date of the xts dateTime index. Thank you.

Comment: It got it by adding as.Date to your code like: as.Date(myDate) %in% as.Date(index(sample.xts)).  The as.Date converts the dateTime back to just the date and checks for a match. For me adding the as.Date makes it 5 times slower than simple index, but it is still hundreds of time faster than what I was doing before.

Comment: I think I could provide an easy counter example. This is essentially [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) all over again:  times can be as finely cut as a double allows, and you generally CANNOT test for equality.

Comment: OP's question was vague - I had to guess a bit at what was wanted. So I guessed it was to determine the existence of a date in a vector of dates. It turned out OP wanted to determine the existence of a date in a vector of datetimes. If I had read the title more carefully perhaps I would have guessed more accurately. OP seems to have found his ultimate answer which is to extract the date from the datetime. I will add commentary to reflect this.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a counter-example to using `%in%`:

```
R> x <- xts(1:20, 
+           order.by=Sys.time() + cumsum(sample(1:10, 20, TRUE)*1e-6))
R> x
                           [,1]
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818800    1
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818805    2
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818809    3
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818810    4
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818819    5
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818827    6
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818832    7
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818837    8
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818843    9
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818847   10
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818848   11
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818849   12
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818858   13
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818867   14
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818872   15
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818877   16
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818881   17
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818888   18
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818889   19
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818890   20
R> reftime <- anytime::anytime("2018-04-05 12:09:12.818832")
R> reftime
[1] "2018-04-05 12:09:12.818831 CDT"
R> reftime %in% index(x)
[1] FALSE
R>
```

I literally copied and pasted a random entry (for value 7) and re-parsed it.  Yet `%in%` fails.

Following [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) you *could* do something like

```
R> which( abs(reftime - index(x)) < 1e-6)
[1] 7
R> 
R> x[which( abs(reftime - index(x)) < 1e-6)]
                           [,1]
2018-04-05 12:09:12.818832    7
R>
```

Comment: Yes %in% only finds exact matches which is why I needed as.Date, but the abs index solution is great and works just like my rcpp code, the only issue I see it that which returns a vector which may be very big for a day. I would be great if it would return at the first value.

Comment: If you need the 'just return one, and fast(er)' it is trivial in C++ as we exit comparisons sooner -- R will always alloc the whole vector.  Otherwise what I showed has the dual advantage of being more correct than your accepted answer and simpler (R only)  ;-)